# How to use class method to stop loop?

Tags: c#

I have class:

```
public class myclass {
  bool b;

  public bool notEnough {
    if (this.b) { return true; }
    else { return false;)
  }
}
```

And try:

```
myclass obj = new myclass;
obj.b = true;
while (obj.notEnough) {
  Thread.Sleep(5);
}
```

In some reason here is error in `(obj.notEnough)`. How to do it right?

Comment: Read the error. It's a method, not a property. Also, `new myclass` won't compile in C#, nor will `public bool notEnough { }`. Please show an example that compiles, or show all compiler errors. Better even, research them yourself.

Comment: This doesn't look like C#

Comment: I think he was trying to create notEnough property, but messed with syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call a method, so you would have to add the parenthesis:

```
myclass obj = new myclass();
obj.b = true;
while (obj.notEnough()) { //Methods are always called by using the parenthesis ()
  Thread.Sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was stupid. Thank you!

Comment: I think he was trying to create `notEnough` property, but messed with syntax.

Comment: Nope. Actual class need method.

Comment: instantiating a class also needs parenthesis after class name

Comment: That won´t even compile because `new myClass` also needs paranthesis. Nevertheless this doesn´t solve the problem on the actual infinite loop.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I simply copied his given code. I didn't check the constructor, so thanks for your comment. I edited that part. And of course you are correct, the infinite loop is still there.

Answer (score 3):

This causes infinite `while` loop. Below is the compiled code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myclass obj = new myclass();
        obj.b = true;
        while (obj.notEnough())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }
}

public class myclass
{
    public bool b;

    public bool notEnough()
    {
        if (this.b)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```